# How to get a partial dump of a postgresql database for non-production environments?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump

I've got 40+ tables, millions of rows per table, hundreds of foreign key relationships and constraints.

I would like to get the entire exact table structure copied over but with say maybe a few hundred or a few thousand rows for creating light development environments.

Thus far, I've only seen pg_dump which, while it can export a single table's partial rows, has no way of exporting a partial database with a few rows per table while **maintaining referential integrity**, that is, if a table depends on some foreign key, make sure there are certain values of that foreign key in the referenced table too so the relationship is intact.

Given the massive number of tables (which change quite frequently), it would be challenging to create and maintain manual `INSERT` commands for so many tables.

Is there any solution for this? (for postgresql specifically)

Comment: Try [This](https://github.com/mla/pg_sample). it may help you with your requirement

Comment: @AkhileshMishra you whould post it as an answer. It's actually nice find, didn't know about such tool. Cool, thanks!

Comment: Agreed! I'm testing it out right now, will report back with how it went. Do post it as an answer :)

Comment: Sadly, pg_sample doesn't seem very stable. I ran into multiple bugs where it isn't able to work with some column types such as json. If it worked, it'd be perfect though, have opened a github issue. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [Jailer](https://github.com/Wisser/Jailer)?
I have had good experiences with it.

**Features:**

- Exports consistent and referentially intact row-sets from your productive database and imports the data into your development and test environment.
- Data Browsing. Navigate bidirectionally through the database by following foreign-key-based or user-defined relationships.
- SQL Console with code completion, syntax highlighting and database metadata visualization.
- A demo database is included with which you can get a first impression without any configuration effort.